# How to convert between different std::chrono duration types?

Tags: c++, std, c++-chrono

For example, if I want to convert from `std::chrono::nanoseconds` to `std::chrono::seconds`, how would I do this?

Comment: Divide by 1000000000. Just kidding, look up `std::chrono::duration_cast`.

Comment: I recommend this chrono video tutorial which covers issues like this:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M  1h.

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for [std::chrono::duration_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/duration_cast):

```
auto seconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(nanoseconds);
```

Comment: Could I pass std::chrono::nanoseconds as parameter in the above duration_cast<> and get the conversion to seconds ?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from [C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration):

duration_cast (C++11) - converts a duration to another, with a different tick interval

You can also use helper types to make period(ratio/unit) conversion without changing representation type:
std::chrono::nanoseconds    -   duration</*signed integer type of at least 64 bits*/, std::nano>

std::chrono::microseconds   -   duration</*signed integer type of at least 55 bits*/, std::micro>

std::chrono::milliseconds   -   duration</*signed integer type of at least 45 bits*/, std::milli>

std::chrono::seconds    -   duration</*signed integer type of at least 35 bits*/>

The example listed at above site shows different conversions (changed a bit):

```
// integer scale conversion with no precision loss: no cast
std::cout << std::chrono::microseconds(time_in_sec).count() << " microseconds\n"
          << shakes(time_in_sec).count() << " shakes\n"
          << std::chrono::milliseconds(time_in_sec).count() << " miliseconds\n"
          << jiffies(time_in_sec).count() << " jiffies\n";

// integer scale conversion with precision loss: requires a cast
std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::minutes>(time_in_sec).count()
          << " minutes\n";

// floating-point scale conversion: no cast
std::cout << microfortnights(time_in_sec).count() << " microfortnights\n"
          << nanocenturies(time_in_sec).count() << " nanocenturies\n"
          << fps_24(time_in_sec).count() << " frames at 24fps\n";
```

Output:

```
5 second(s) is:
5000000000 nanoseconds
500000000 shakes
5000000 microseconds
5000 miliseconds
500 jiffies
0 minutes
4.1336 microfortnights
1.58444 nanocenturies
120 frames at 24fps
```

[See full code at CE (needs C++20)](https://godbolt.org/z/PqP7acxK4)

P.S. You can play with the values of time_in_sec to see where conversion breaks (hint: try 42)